# Перебор символов кириллицы в bat

Tags: cmd, bat

Я только начала осваивать синтаксис батников и 
столкнулась с проблемой, когда мне надо было сделать перебор русских символов. То есть программа начинается с буквы а

`aaaaa
aaaaб
аааав
...
баааа
баааб
...
яяяяя`

Ну и заканчивается, соответственно, буквой я. 
Ничего полезного по этой теме в интернете не нашла. Буду рада вашей помощи! :)

Comment: Может стоит воспользоваться каким-нибудь нормальным языком программирования? Даже у линуксового bash гораздо больше возможностей, чем у батников.

Comment: Не спорю, да вот задание подразумевает использование именно батника

Comment: Самый простой подход и красивый подход: использование рекурсии, **но** у пакетных файлов есть лимит стека вызовов. Поэтому от этого способа придется отказаться. Дальнейший логичный шаг - **итерация**. Лично я бы (не сильно заморачиваясь) строил основной текстовый словарь (выводил слова в файл). А в цикле просто добавлял бы символы из алфавита в конец, к уже построенному словарю, строя новую часть словаря отдельным файлом. По завершении цикла копировал (добавлением) к текстовому словарю новую часть словаря.